# NSURLSession background transfer not working

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask, nsurlsessionuploadtask, nsurlsessionconfiguration

I’m trying to download a series of files from server to iOS app, with the intent that the download of these files happen even when the App is in the **background mode**.

I'm using **background transfer** provided by *NSURLSession* and its series of APIs.

I initiated download task when app was running in foreground mode and it gave me expected result as series of download was working good but if I press the home button when series of download is in progress then it will stop immediately and when I go into the app again download shall resume.

If say it in simple words **background transfer** isn’t even working me.

**EDIT**

**Initially I was testing this in simulator it didn’t work well and someone commented to test the same in real device, so I tested it by connecting real device in debug mode it really worked well and I thought everything was solved but again it gave me a shock that is if I disconnect the device from Xcode and check app, it did not work at all :(**

I created a sample application to demonstrate this issue, please download it from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l83gp1i2ebpw38l/URLSessionSample-2.zip?dl=0)

**Note:** In this sample application I reinitiated download call in the *didFinishDownloadingToURL* to simulate series of download files

Can you anyone please help me to solve this?

Comment: Please post relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You have not selected the correct background mode in the **Capabilities** tab. Check the **Background fetch** option. 
[image: Background fetch option not checked]

Also, if you are testing in the simulator only, click on **Debug -> Simulate Background Fetch** in the menu. Otherwise, the background fetch will not be initiated in the simulator.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I guess just to use background transfer (NSURLSessionTask) we don't need to enable background fetch. I am assuming background fetch is completely different.

Comment: You're welcome :) . You will eventually need to check the background fetch feature to pass the apple review when sending your app to the app store.

Comment: Oh really? If possible can you please share me a link which says enabling background fetch is must to pass review?

Comment: Checkout this tutorial from raywenderlich. https://www.raywenderlich.com/143128/background-modes-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: But here is a contradictory piece of information which says its optional. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html . So I guess since Apple says its optional, it is indeed optional. Never knew that. Should dig on it some more. Sorry for the misinformation. But in any case I will not take any chances with my app for now :).

Comment: The background fetch checkbox is for a distantly related feature that allows your app to be periodically launched in the background to fetch resources (e.g. for a newspaper's application to periodically fetch the latest news).